# Problems with the placing of a div

Tags: html, css, position

I have some issues with a div ->

```css
#Next-Level, #Last-Level {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
}

#Next-Level {
    top:0px;
    border-bottom:5px red dotted;
}

#Last-Level {
    bottom:0px;
    border-top:5px blue dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="Levels">    
    <div id="Last-Level"></div>
    <div id="Current-Level"></div>
    <div id="Next-Level"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zwzh64wb/
- I want to make the div "Current-Level" between "Last-Level" and "Next-Level" and I don't understand how..

Comment: is position:fixed a mandatory condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    #Next-Level, #Last-Level {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        position:fixed;
        left:0px;
}
    #Current-Level {
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        position:fixed;
        top:150px;
}
        

    #Next-Level {
       top:0px;border-bottom:5px red dotted;
}
    #Last-Level {
       bottom:0px;border-top:5px blue dotted;
}
    #Current-Level {
       bottom:0px;border-top:5px green dotted;
}
    <div id="Levels">    
        <div id="Last-Level"></div>
        <div id="Current-Level"></div>
        <div id="Next-Level"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a current level `div` element, but haven't defined the CSS properties for the same. Just like First-Level and Last-LeveL, you'll have to specify the CSS properties for Current-Level.

[Click this to check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/mg4uux74/)

```
#Next-Level, #Last-Level, #Current-Level {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;}

#Next-Level {top:0px;border-bottom:5px red dotted;}
#Last-Level {bottom:0px;border-top:5px blue dotted;}
#Current-Level {margin-top:33%;border-top:5px black dotted;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
#Next-Level, #Last-Level {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    }

#Next-Level {border-bottom:5px red dotted;}
#Last-Level {border-top:5px blue dotted;}
#Current-Level {border-bottom:5px black dotted;}
```

```html
<div id="Levels">    
    <div id="Last-Level"></div>
    <div id="Current-Level"></div>
    <div id="Next-Level"></div>
</div>
```